# Efficient ways to compute nth root in C++ without using cmath

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, c++20, nth-root

How to efficiently compute nth root of a number to at least 12 correct decimal places without using cmath and such?

I have tried to solve it myself. My idea is to find an approximation and use Newton's method to make the approximation more accurate.

I have implemented 2 methods, one using binary search, the other one is based on the fast inverse square root algorithm.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
float r = 0.0;

inline float power(float base, int exp) {
    if (not exp) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    if (exp < 0) {
        base = 1 / base;
        exp = -exp;
    }
    float p = 1.0;
    while (exp > 1) {
        if (exp % 2) {
            p = base * p;
        }
        base *= base;
        exp /= 2;
    }
    return base * p;
}

inline float nth_root(float base, int n) {
    float lo, hi, x, p, r, v;
    int n1 = n - 1;
    lo = 0;
    hi = base;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        x = (lo + hi) / 2;
        p = power(x, n1);
        v = x * p - base;
        r = n * p;
        if (v <= 0) {
            lo = x;
        }
        else {
            hi = x;
        }
    }
    x = (lo + hi) / 2;
    r = 1.0 / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        x = r * (n * x + base / power(x, n));
    }
    return x;
}

inline float fast_nth_root(float base, int n)
{
   uint32_t i = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(base);
   float rn = 1.0 / n;
   i = 0x3F7A3BEA * rn * (n + 1) - i * rn;
   float x = std::bit_cast<float>(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
       x = x * (n + 1 - base * power(x, n)) * rn;
   }
   return 1.0 / x;
}

int main()
{
    vector<float> bases(256);
    vector<int> ns(256);
    float r256 = 1.0 / 256;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        bases[i] = 1.0 + rand() % 16384 + (rand() % 256) * r256;
        ns[i] = 2 + rand() % 30;
    }
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += nth_root(bases[i % 256], ns[i % 256]);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    cout << "nth_root: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += pow(bases[i % 256], 1.0 / ns[i % 256]);
    }
    end = steady_clock::now();
    time = end - start;
    cout << "pow: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r += fast_nth_root(bases[i % 256], ns[i % 256]);
    }
    end = steady_clock::now();
    time = end - start;
    cout << "fast_nth_root: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -fexpensive-optimizations -flto -O3 -m64 --std=c++20 -march=native -ffast-math  -c D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Release\testapp.exe obj\Release\main.o  -O3 -flto -s -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m64
```

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\bin\Release\testapp.exe
nth_root: 318.12 nanoseconds
pow: 104.77 nanoseconds
fast_nth_root: 53.4222 nanoseconds
```

The first method is very slow, as expected, but though the second method is faster than the library code it may be not as accurate.

According to my tests in Python:

```py
import random, struct

def root(num, p, lim, lin):
    lo = 0
    hi = num
    for _ in range(lim):
        x = (lo + hi) / 2
        po = x ** (p - 1)
        v = x * po - num
        r = p * po
        if v <= 0:
            lo = x
        else:
            hi = x

    x = (lo + hi) / 2
    r = 1 / p
    p -= 1
    for _ in range(lin):
        x = r * (p * x + num / x ** p)
    
    return x

stats = {}
for _ in range(64):
    n = random.randrange(1, 16384)
    p = random.randrange(2, 32)
    x = n ** (1 / p)
    i = 2
    j = 2
    b = 0
    while abs((y := root(n, p, i, j)) - x) > 1e-13:
        if i < 16 and b or i >= 16:
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
        b = not b

    stats[(n, p)] = (i, j, x, y)

def fast_nth_root(x: float, n: int, lim: int) -> float:
    t = int.from_bytes(struct.pack('>f', x), 'big')
    t = round(0x3F7A3BEA / n * (n + 1) - t / n)
    t = struct.unpack('>f', struct.pack('>i', t))[0]
    for _ in range(lim):
        t = t * (n + 1 - x * t ** n) / n
    
    return 1 / t


stats1 = {}
for _ in range(64):
    n = random.randrange(1, 16384)
    p = random.randrange(2, 32)
    x = n ** (1 / p)
    i = 2
    while abs((y := fast_nth_root(n, p, i)) - x) > 1e-13:
        i += 1

    stats1[(n, p)] = (i, x, y)
```

```
In [1434]: stats
Out[1434]:
{(7162, 13): (11, 10, 1.979434344458145, 1.979434344458145),
 (15510, 2): (5, 5, 124.53915047084591, 124.53915047084595),
 (3054, 25): (10, 9, 1.3784618821753079, 1.3784618821753076),
 (1601, 25): (9, 8, 1.3433081611539914, 1.3433081611540099),
 (3522, 21): (10, 9, 1.475348878994169, 1.475348878994169),
 (15107, 14): (12, 11, 1.9884410975573956, 1.9884410975573954),
 (15200, 16): (12, 11, 1.8254301706001883, 1.825430170600188),
 (1900, 15): (9, 8, 1.6541830766301984, 1.6541830766301981),
 (16145, 20): (12, 11, 1.6233116388185762, 1.623311638818576),
 (2580, 4): (7, 6, 7.126969930959522, 7.126969930959522),
 (1702, 27): (11, 10, 1.3172407839773748, 1.3172407839773748),
 (9875, 29): (13, 13, 1.3732280275029944, 1.3732280275029942),
 (15687, 15): (12, 11, 1.9041565885196923, 1.904156588519692),
 (5774, 16): (12, 11, 1.718273525571221, 1.718273525571221),
 (6186, 2): (5, 4, 78.65112840894274, 78.65112840894277),
 (4476, 23): (12, 11, 1.441233509663115, 1.441233509663115),
 (4161, 24): (12, 11, 1.4151416228042228, 1.4151416228042226),
 (16116, 13): (12, 11, 2.1068575543742956, 2.1068575543742956),
 (12380, 14): (11, 11, 1.9603661231094314, 1.9603661231094311),
 (9736, 19): (13, 12, 1.621491836717726, 1.6214918367177258),
 (8612, 26): (13, 12, 1.4169357394205302, 1.4169357394205302),
 (4586, 7): (9, 8, 3.334740217355978, 3.3347402173559777),
 (5232, 24): (12, 12, 1.428711330576587, 1.4287113305765868),
 (14698, 17): (12, 11, 1.7584613929955697, 1.7584613929955695),
 (4931, 13): (10, 9, 1.923410237452901, 1.9234102374529014),
 (7391, 4): (8, 7, 9.272050761175075, 9.272050761175075),
 (9949, 6): (9, 9, 4.637635073009885, 4.637635073009886),
 (4767, 18): (12, 11, 1.6008364077669808, 1.6008364077669806),
 (16318, 8): (11, 10, 3.3618889684623863, 3.3618889684623863),
 (7610, 28): (13, 12, 1.3760077520394016, 1.3760077520394014),
 (13632, 6): (10, 9, 4.887573066390476, 4.887573066390476),
 (8380, 21): (11, 11, 1.5375213098103222, 1.5375213098103224),
 (7247, 14): (11, 10, 1.88679879448582, 1.8867987944858202),
 (11343, 18): (13, 12, 1.6798196720467486, 1.6798196720467486),
 (6468, 17): (11, 10, 1.6755714114675964, 1.6755714114675964),
 (11801, 6): (10, 9, 4.771480299610415, 4.771480299610415),
 (441, 28): (9, 8, 1.2429230307022932, 1.2429230307022932),
 (15341, 14): (12, 11, 1.9906254301097404, 1.9906254301097404),
 (8501, 20): (11, 10, 1.5720758667453518, 1.5720758667453518),
 (2777, 19): (10, 10, 1.5178918732605664, 1.5178918732605664),
 (14842, 30): (14, 13, 1.3773672345540857, 1.3773672345540857),
 (6149, 28): (11, 10, 1.3655715058830975, 1.3655715058830973),
 (13374, 21): (12, 11, 1.5721306482454025, 1.5721306482454025),
 (9947, 30): (13, 13, 1.3591156205784112, 1.359115620578415),
 (14423, 16): (12, 11, 1.8194535606369682, 1.8194535606369682),
 (9341, 31): (13, 12, 1.3430036888404402, 1.3430036888404402),
 (14558, 7): (10, 9, 3.9330441035217714, 3.9330441035217714),
 (152, 16): (8, 7, 1.3688795144738382, 1.368879514473838),
 (13593, 18): (12, 11, 1.6967920812890351, 1.6967920812890351),
 (2834, 7): (8, 8, 3.113149507653915, 3.1131495076539637),
 (11545, 14): (11, 10, 1.950612466604169, 1.9506124666041689),
 (12416, 21): (12, 11, 1.566576147387506, 1.5665761473875057),
 (8998, 6): (9, 8, 4.560624662646501, 4.560624662646504),
 (5245, 27): (11, 10, 1.3733092699013858, 1.3733092699013856),
 (5693, 29): (11, 10, 1.3473937347050562, 1.3473937347050562),
 (3508, 26): (10, 10, 1.3688266297365765, 1.368826629736599),
 (16237, 9): (11, 10, 2.936526854011741, 2.936526854011741),
 (2911, 6): (8, 7, 3.778682197915392, 3.7786821979153924),
 (387, 22): (10, 9, 1.311061987204142, 1.311061987204142),
 (3324, 4): (7, 7, 7.593032412784651, 7.593032412784651),
 (15300, 22): (12, 11, 1.5495773040868939, 1.5495773040868939),
 (5469, 26): (11, 10, 1.3924053694535468, 1.392405369453547),
 (1195, 13): (8, 8, 1.7247279767538015, 1.724727976753898),
 (7998, 13): (11, 10, 1.9963162339549785, 1.9963162339549787)}

In [1435]: stats1
Out[1435]:
{(10882, 3): (4, 22.159990703206965, 22.159990703206965),
 (6673, 28): (6, 1.3695657835909767, 1.3695657835909767),
 (4803, 10): (4, 2.3342709144708604, 2.3342709144708604),
 (1802, 27): (5, 1.3200291160996098, 1.3200291160996294),
 (8380, 15): (4, 1.8262053100463662, 1.826205310046366),
 (12898, 21): (5, 1.569419919895426, 1.5694199198954262),
 (10227, 2): (4, 101.12863096077193, 101.12863096077193),
 (4857, 25): (5, 1.4042832772764529, 1.4042832772765208),
 (1351, 12): (4, 1.8234251715932501, 1.8234251715932501),
 (10180, 16): (3, 1.7802632882832108, 1.7802632882832108),
 (6948, 28): (6, 1.37154252932099, 1.3715425293209902),
 (13901, 10): (4, 2.5959994991170756, 2.5959994991171),
 (7513, 21): (5, 1.529545998990047, 1.529545998990047),
 (7902, 18): (4, 1.6464211857566509, 1.6464211857566777),
 (3277, 31): (6, 1.2983819395882321, 1.2983819395882321),
 (3499, 10): (4, 2.261488555258189, 2.2614885552581887),
 (15234, 30): (6, 1.3785646304878574, 1.3785646304878574),
 (5739, 13): (5, 1.9459928850146935, 1.9459928850146935),
 (1823, 24): (5, 1.3673072329614473, 1.367307232961453),
 (15105, 16): (4, 1.8247150144295399, 1.8247150144295399),
 (16215, 12): (3, 2.2429852247131876, 2.2429852247131876),
 (15844, 20): (5, 1.6217848596088165, 1.6217848596088162),
 (15677, 26): (5, 1.4499608216310222, 1.4499608216310922),
 (11839, 22): (5, 1.5316187797414815, 1.5316187797414818),
 (10163, 26): (6, 1.4259891723870766, 1.4259891723870766),
 (1550, 18): (5, 1.5039751132184096, 1.5039751132184096),
 (15194, 5): (4, 6.8601628355219795, 6.860162835521979),
 (15612, 24): (5, 1.4952969217858556, 1.495296921785857),
 (9469, 12): (4, 2.1446611088057317, 2.144661108805732),
 (4030, 20): (5, 1.5144859625611744, 1.5144859625611742),
 (11729, 3): (4, 22.720627875592783, 22.72062787559279),
 (12709, 29): (6, 1.3852274277113097, 1.3852274277113097),
 (12263, 31): (6, 1.354846884624788, 1.354846884624788),
 (6372, 9): (4, 2.6466548424778766, 2.6466548424779086),
 (7119, 5): (4, 5.8949998528103436, 5.8949998528103436),
 (10737, 27): (6, 1.4102365332846034, 1.4102365332846034),
 (2231, 11): (4, 2.01562182326949, 2.0156218232694902),
 (412, 9): (4, 1.952289125066342, 1.9522891250663446),
 (8417, 5): (4, 6.095810609109851, 6.095810609109851),
 (6759, 31): (6, 1.3290600231725829, 1.3290600231725826),
 (2207, 23): (5, 1.3975994148304356, 1.3975994148304371),
 (4755, 16): (4, 1.6975473914419268, 1.697547391441927),
 (7978, 13): (4, 1.995931787083301, 1.9959317870833602),
 (14957, 19): (4, 1.658550339552885, 1.658550339552935),
 (745, 28): (5, 1.2664178106847905, 1.2664178106847914),
 (2696, 15): (4, 1.6932249497186587, 1.6932249497186587),
 (5484, 7): (4, 3.421029175738748, 3.421029175738748),
 (15410, 10): (4, 2.6228911266357167, 2.6228911266357264),
 (315, 10): (3, 1.7775877772276876, 1.7775877772276876),
 (9252, 13): (4, 2.0188081438649, 2.0188081438649035),
 (1562, 27): (5, 1.313059731029047, 1.3130597310290748),
 (9803, 8): (4, 3.1544225980493534, 3.154422598049354),
 (14443, 16): (4, 1.8196111450479415, 1.8196111450479413),
 (5033, 23): (5, 1.4486017214956801, 1.4486017214956872),
 (16175, 2): (4, 127.18097341976905, 127.18097341976903),
 (15125, 5): (4, 6.853920721113647, 6.853920721113645),
 (16292, 19): (4, 1.6660301757087943, 1.666030175708797),
 (11486, 20): (5, 1.5959101637580406, 1.5959101637580406),
 (13824, 7): (4, 3.9040835527337374, 3.9040835527337383),
 (8604, 3): (4, 20.491172086350442, 20.491172086350442),
 (1225, 3): (4, 10.699874805650794, 10.699874805650795),
 (9163, 21): (5, 1.54407524840236, 1.5440752484023603),
 (7833, 21): (5, 1.53258704058841, 1.53258704058841),
 (8425, 24): (5, 1.4573551932369144, 1.4573551932369178)}
```

On average for the first method roughly 12 iterations of binary search and 12 iterations of Newton's method are needed to get the error below 10<sup>-13</sup>, and 6 iterations of Newton's method are needed for the second method to get the same accuracy.

Are there ways to make the code run faster for the same number of iterations, or ways to speed up the convergence rate of the math involved?

---

This is not an assignment. It is a self-imposed programming challenge.

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the problem that your own `power` function solves, that `std::pow` doesn't?

Comment: What is your actual assignment? What are its requirements? What are its limitations? The "without library" part you mention is negated by you using plenty of C++ standard library code. You can't even do output without using a library. If it's just the mathematical functions that are supposed to be done without "library functions" then you should not even use `std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(base)`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `float`? Unless you have very specific requirements, you should be using `double` instead. And no, it won't be less "effective" or less "optimal". And why is `r` a global variable? You shadow it in the `nth_root` function, and its use could be local in the `main` function.

Comment: And by the way, is the code you show ***working*** (a hard requirement)? Then since what you're really seem to be asking about is a code-review, you should be posting on [the code-review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (but make sure it's really [on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude These are nit picks that don't really contribute much the the conversation. Either by addressing the question or the concerns about the degree of the limitations on library code.

Comment: I don't know the rules of c++ but in c at least, casting a float to a uint32_t is a strict aliasing violation. In c, the proper way to do it is with a union or memcpy. Also, as has already been said, you can't have 12 significant digits with floats, so your analysis of your results looks suspicious.

Comment: I suggest you check the assembler to see if the if (exp % 2) is coded as a conditional move rather than a branch. You could try using a ternary operator to try to get it to use a cmov.

Comment: I'd second the suggestion to get a code review. There are quite a few points where the clarity of the code could be improved, which could also make it easier for an optimizer (be it the one in the compiler or a human) to improve it. I'd also `assert()` assumptions, as part of these improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what range of values your function should cover, nor the statistical distribution of these values, so we have to suggest a general-purpose method.

The strategy is to first find a good initial approximation for Newton's iterations by working on the order of magnitude.

If you have access to the exponent of the floating-point representation (by hacking the binary representation), a good starting value is √2/2 times 2^(exponent/n). We choose √2/2 rather than 1 to be centered on [1/2, 1). For efficiency, you can precompute these constants for all exponents and all root orders. Anyway, to save space, it can be better to decompose the exponent over n in integer quotient and remainder.

If the exponent is not available, then you can search for it by successive doublings (or halvings), starting from 1 (so 1=2^0, 2=2^1, 4=2^2, 8=2^3...). This amounts to a linear search among the exponents. Yet more efficient is to work with squarings, and implement an exponential search among the exponents (you are doubling the powers each time, 2=2^1, 4=2^2, 16=2^4, 256=2^8...). After you have found a possible range of exponents, revert to linear search. You can also optimize with precomputed values.

Finally, you can start with Newton's iterations. For the case of the square-root, you can work with the inverse square root to avoid division. Unfortunately, this does not generalize to hight orders.

Last but not least, it may be beneficial to determine the number of iterations required in the worst case (with the worst initial approximation), and always use this number, rather than test for convergence with a certain tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

Using binary search to get an initial guess for `nth_root` is not particularly efficient.

You can use a hack on the floating point representation similar to the one in `fast_nth...`, before proceeding with a proper Newton's method implementation.

Something like:

```
constexpr int32_t ONE_BITS = std::bit_cast<int32_t>(1.0f);

inline float nth_root(float base, int n) {
    int32_t x_bits = std::bit_cast<int32_t>(base);
    x_bits = (x_bits - ONE_BITS)/n + ONE_BITS;
    // first guess
    float x = std::bit_cast<float>(x_bits);
```

The important effect of this is just that it divides the floating point exponent by `n`.

Comment: You shouldn't play with floating point binary representation if you are concerned with portability, it's not standardized. You can access the exponent through std function though, which is the only portable way to do so (yet it might have an overhead with respect to accessing the underlying memory directly if it happens to work on a given architecture/compiler).

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid `cmath` functions and similar.

Comment: understood, yet does he want its implementation to be portable? He should tell us in order to have more pertinent answers.

Comment: @Oersted Actually, it *is* standardized. The IEEE-754 standard specify the exact representation of 32-bits floats (more specifically, the IEC-559 one). All mainstream platforms support it properly since more than a decade now. This include Intel and AMD x86-64 processors, and ARM as well as RISC processors (AFAIK >99% of the Server/PC/Mobile market share). Even mainstream GPU are IEEE-754 compliant these days. Only some rare exotic embedded-devices might not support that. Anyway, the compliance can be checked in C++ using `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559;` if needed.

Comment: @JérômeRichard As far as I understood, IEEE-754 only propose the memory layout but not impose. If it is not so, I would appreciate the wording to be pinpointed. Besides, I'm not "fluent" in nomenclature of standards: what is the difference, if any, between iec559 and IEEE-754? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From C++ standard: *There are three floating-point types: float, double, and long double... The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined...* And, before: *The value representation of an object of type T is the set of bits that participate in representing a value of type T*

Comment: @Oersted The IEC-559 and IEEE-754 [are basically the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (besides some nitpicking on standardization methods/organizations).  The C++ standard does not enforce the IEEE-754/IEC-559 norm, but as I said previously, it can be checked using a static assert (`is_iec559`) and I am not aware of any (recent) mainstream platform where `is_iec559` is `False`.

Comment: @Oersted The IEEE-754 does not *propose* a layout, i.e. this is not optional if the target platform *supports* it. Otherwise, the standard would be pointless. The standard *defines/specifies* the layout (see [here](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~cnum/modulos/Modulo2/IEEE754_2008.pdf)). E.g. *"This clause defines floating-point formats"* ; *"Each floating-point number has just one encoding in a binary interchange format."* ; *"A programming environment conforms to this standard, in a particular radix, by implementing [...] interchange format."* . Besides, most chapters use the word "shall".

Comment: Thank you for the precisions. The other way around, in the case of is_iec559 being false, does significand and exponent still supposed to be defined? (is ```std::frexp``` well defined?)